# Update gmake in FreeBsd 9.2

Tags: freebsd

I need to get the newest version of gnu make for freebsd 9.2.

I tried

```
pkg update gcc
```

and got this output:

```
Usage: pkg update [-fq] [-r reponame]

For more information, see 'pkg help update'.
```

and

```
pkg install gcc
```

with the following output:

```
No active remote repositories configured.
```

And both did not work. I hope you can help me

Comment: If you want to update `make`, why are you giving `gcc` as the package name? They're two different things.

Comment: because gmake comes from gcc as far as I know

Comment: No, it doesn't. `gcc` and GNU `make` (sometimes called `gmake`) are separate projects, both managed by GNU / the FSF.

Answer (score 1):

```
pkg update
```

to get updates
and then

```
pkg install -f [pkgname]
```

To force instalation of just single package [pkgname] after update of repositories and to avoid updating all packages installed

Comment: root@host:~ # pkg install -f [gcc]
pkg: No match.
root@host:~ # pkg install -f [gmake]
pkg: No match.

Comment: Without  [ and ] around package name. ;) It's just a convention to highlight the fact that it is not a part of pkg install syntax and you should put package name there.